# Compare treeView nodes Text to a String

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, nodes

I'm working on a Winform application, how can I check if there is a treeNode that its text is inside `string Mystring`? And how can i retrieve the tag of this node please?

```
if (myString.Contains(treeView1.Nodes.ToString()))
```

Comment: hmmm, with your sample code, treeView1.Nodes will only check the first hierarchy level of TreeView. Is that what you want, or do you wanna compare with all the Nodes of the treeView's hierarchy ?

Comment: I wanna compare with all Nodes but I don't find how to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for only first matched node.

```
private TreeNode FindMatchedNode(TreeNodeCollection tnCol, string text)
{
    TreeNode tn = null;

    foreach (TreeNode node in tnCol)
    {
        if (text.ToLower().Contains(node.Text.ToLower()))
        {
            tn = node;
            break;
        }
        else if (node.Nodes != null)
        {
            tn = FindNode(node.Nodes, text);

            if (tn != null)
                break;
        }
    }

    return tn;
}
```

and for all matched nodes

```
private List<TreeNode> FindAllMatchedNodes(TreeNodeCollection tnCol, string text)
{
    List<TreeNode> retVal = new List<TreeNode>();

    foreach (TreeNode node in tnCol)
    {
        if (text.ToLower().Contains(node.Text.ToLower()))
        {
            retVal.Add(node);
        }
        else if (node.Nodes != null)
        {
            retVal.AddRange(FindNode(node.Nodes, text));
        }
    }

    return retVal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This method will traverse tree from root and find first node that `Text` is inside of `myString`

```
public object FindNode()
{
    var queue = new Queue<TreeNode>();

    foreach (var n in treeView1.Nodes)
    {
         // Add all root nodes to queue
         queue.Enqueue(n);
    }

    while (queue.Count > 0)
    {
        // Take the next node from the front of the queue
        var node = queue.Dequeue();

        // Check if myString contains node text
        if (myString.Contains(node.Text))
            return node.Tag;

        // Add the node’s children to the back of the queue
        foreach (var child in node.Children)
        {
            queue.Enqueue(child);
        }
    }

    // None of the nodes matched the specified string.
    return null;
}
```

Comment: `var queue = new Queue<Node>();`:`<Node>` is not reconized.. a directive is missing...?

Comment: `node.Text` and `node.Tag` and `node.Children` also not recognized!